# How to continue to the end of duration for indefinite animation on mouse out

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I want to create an SVG that has the animation attributes that can continue the animation on mouse over.

On mouse out, I want the animation to continue to its end of duration before ending.

I am unable to achieve this as my animation always ends abruptly.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- Simple color fill -->
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="teal" >
<animate attributeName="fill" values="teal;cyan;teal;" dur="1s" calcMode="paced" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="mouseover" end="mouseout" />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Understand that we can achieve a slightly seamless feel by adding the `fill="freeze"` attribute.

However it brings back the issue of the colour not being the same as from where it left off.

Any idea how we can create a smooth animation on mouse over just by using svg attributes?

I hope to not use Javascript.

Comment: try `repeatCount="1" begin="mouseover; mouseout" fill="freeze"`

Comment: For that attribute set, the animation does not continue as an ongoing process on mouse hover, and there is a slight jitter on mouse out.